# Problems with django rest framework default field validation

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following problems for a nested model like this:

```
def Post(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()

def Comment(models.Model)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    content = models.CharField()
```

I created default model serializers with **all** fields.

Problems:

1. The default model serializer does not work for nested models. I have to explicitly write create/update. This has been explained in the documentation, so nothing against it. Although I think choosing sane default can cater to 99% of use cases (and for the rest, behaviour can be customisable). I will try to take a shot at this.
2. When I try to use json from existing post object, serializer is_valid() fails saying "unique constraint on name fails". But I wanted it to update and not create. Should is_valid not be create/update aware based on id being passed in json.
3. When creating a new nested json with many comments, is_valid() fails saying that "post is empty". Of course I will not have post id in the json, as post creation is yet to happen. So is_valid becomes useless. Should is_valid not depend on if id is passed in json? Also, I can not use data/validated_data without having is_valid pass.
4. Setting validators = [] also does not remove field validations. I have not yet found a way to suppress field validations.

I have gone through source code and documentation and spent more than a day to set up something so simple.

I must be missing something simple, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to create the post already with the comments or this action can be separated in two steps? One to create the post and another to add a comment to an existing post

Comment: Either way is fine. Ideally for any nested object (e.g. An article with multiple sources, writers, tags etc.), creation or update in one shot is preferred. I am looking for rest standard/best practices, will update here after that.